# Continuous extension of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm actually following a Brownian motion course, unfortunately I'm stuck with the following. Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ on this probability space.

We are interested in the property $(*)$ which is,

> **Property** ($*$): *It is possible to find some probability space $(\tilde{\Omega}, \mathcal{L},\mathbb{Q})$, and some random process $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ on this probability space with $(Y)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}\stackrel{\text{fdd}}=(X)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}$ and such that there exists a measurable set with probability 1, such that for all $\omega$ in this set, $t\mapsto Y_t(\omega)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$.*

Here, $(Y)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}\stackrel{\text{fdd}}=(X)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}$ means that the two processes have the same finite dimensional distributions.

Now suppose that our $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ have the $(*)$ property. The statement is the following: suppose $J$ is a **countable** dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$ (for instance $\mathbb{Q}^+$) and one has a collection of random variables $(Z_q)_{q\in J}$ with the same fdds as $(X_q)_{q \in J}$ (this is really a property about the law in particular we do not suppose anything about the probability space of $(Z_q)_{q\in J}$), **then $(Z_q)_{q\in J}$ almost surely has a continuous extension. In addition this extension $(\tilde{Z_t})_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is such that $(\tilde{Z}_t)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}\stackrel{\text{fdd}}=(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}$**.

I've tried to prove the above without success for a long time thus I will greatly appreciate if any of you can help me with that :)

Have a great day.

Comment: Your notation was causing both FOE and me confusion, so I edited with what I think is an improvement. You are welcome to re-edit with a different change, but I would suggest staying away from $X$ to refer to the set of fdds of $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}$, since $X$ looks too much like the notation for the actual process itself.

Comment: You're absolutely right. You're edit is perfect thanks for the improvement :)